# Putting a famous quote in LyX

Tags: lyx, epigraphs

**EDIT**: By a comment below, I learned that what I'm asking is: How do I add an epigraph in the beginning of a section?

**EDIT**: I managed to use the epigraph package. I'm importing it in the LaTeX preable and in my document open a LaTeX red box and write: `\epigraph{the quote}{the author}`. It looks pretty much fine.

In LyX, I would like to add a famous

> ``If you can't solve a problem, then there is an easier problem you can solve: find it.''
>
> George Pólya

I'd like the whole thing to be slightly indented, and name "George Pólya" much more indented. Is there a standard way to do that? I tried the "Quotation" and "Quote" envionment, but they seem to slightly indent the whole paragraph, which is not exactly what I want.

(and, by the way, is this a good practice, or is there another way a quote should look like?)

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to write an epigraph? That's a quote (usually a famous one) at the start of a section or chapter, and it usually looks pretty much like what you describe. Depending on the class you are using, there are ready-made environments or packages for such things.

Comment: Yes, it's an epigraph (I've just now learned this word). How do I add one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`epigraph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph) package for this. The line width and other things can be customised according to the [documentation](http://mirrors.linsrv.net/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/epigraph/epigraph.pdf).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\begin{document}

\epigraph{`If you can't solve a problem, then there is an easier problem you can solve: find it.''}{George Pólya}

\end{document}
```

Note that if you are using the `memoir` class, it already includes a similar set of macros for epigraphs (in which case, read the `memoir` documentation for customisations).